# Error while i try to commit changes in Git via Visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, gitignore, git-commit, git-repo

I`m trying to commit to my DevOps using Git source. for some reason I cannot proceed with the commit phase.

The error:

```
Git failed with a fatal error.
error: open("FinalWorkFinder/FinalWorkFinder/App_Data/aspnet-FinalWorkFinder-20190303122718.mdf"): Permission denied
fatal: Unable to process path FinalWorkFinder/FinalWorkFinder/App_Data/aspnet-FinalWorkFinder-20190303122718.mdf
```

If I go to repository settings, I can see that there is already a `.gitignore` file, but it does not ignore `.mdf`.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, try and double-check that status from the command-line:

```
git status
```

If the file is ignored and yet still tracked, do:

```
git rm --cached -- FinalWorkFinder/FinalWorkFinder/App_Data/aspnet-FinalWorkFinder-20190303122718.mdf
```

Make sure it is actually ignored with:

```
git check-ignore -v -- FinalWorkFinder/FinalWorkFinder/App_Data/aspnet-FinalWorkFinder-20190303122718.mdf
```

Followed by a `git commit`: see if the issue persists for future commits.